# Ping implementation approach for web application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I've a java based web application running on Tomcat and it uses spring framework. I need to expose a ping URL to check whether the application is up and running. I've considered the following implementation approaches and all of them seems to work well when I tried them. However, I could not make up my mind whether one approach is better than another. Does it matter which path I take? Could someone advise which approach is better and why?

1. Create a web page and modify web.xml to redirect the url to the jsp page.
2. Create a REST service using Spring-WS
3. Create a servlet and return response

Answer (score 1):

Use anything you want :-) But notice, that both Spring-WS and JSP are a little heavier (really not a meaningful reason here) than servlets. If you already have REST API to your aplication, use Spring-WS, if you render pages through JSP, use JSP. Or if you use none of these, write a plain servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spring, assuming you use Spring MVC, you can just add another controller mapped to a certain URL which would be responsible for returning a status. 
Solution 1 might not work depending on your requirement since a jsp  page might work even if the rest of the app does not since it is not part of spring config.